# How to create multiple calculated columns on the value of one colum which refers to other columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-munging

I am trying to create a time series which shows what the values of a specific Column was at a particular time. All I currently have access to is a table which logs all the changes, the current value of the columns, dates and the names of the column which was altered. I would like to create a new column which tracks what the previous value of the column was before it was changed. There are over 63 distinct columns in the change log referenced in ‘Column_name’

This is what I currently have

```
________________________________________________
Name |  date    |A  | B  |C  |NEW | Column_name|
bob  |  12302019|2  | 23 |153|2   | a          | 
bob  |  12102019|2  | 23 |153|362 | a          |
bob  |  10242019|2  | 23 |153|7   | a          |
john |  10062017|684| 452|1  |254 | c          |
john |  11052018|684| 452|1  |1   | c          |
________________________________________________
```

This is what I would like help Creating

```
_________________________________________________________________________________
Name |  date    |A  | B  |C  |NEW | Column_name| a_ at Date| b_ at Date | c_ at Date |
bob  |  12302019|2  | 23 |153|2   | a          |2          | 23         | 153        |
bob  |  12102019|2  | 23 |153|362 | a          |362        | 23         | 153        |
bob  |  10242019|2  | 23 |153|7   | a          |7          | 23         | 153        |
john |  10062017|684| 452|1  |254 | c          |684        | 452        | 254        | 
john |  11052018|684| 452|1  |1   | c          |684        | 452        | 1          | 
______________________________________________________________________________________     
I have tested the solution on the following test Data frame, where there is only one column Name "A" and it has several factors 
'data.frame':   755 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ name       : int  606765182 83595892 538663788 779873188 957405600 522796409 41212559 145402647 304688204 83595892 ...
 $ date       : POSIXct, format: "2019-11-01" "2019-11-01" "2019-10-21" ...
 $ A          : Factor
 $ B          : Factor
 $ C          : Factor

 $ Column_name: Factor w/ 1
 $ NEW        : Factor w/ 8
```

Comment: Why uppercase column names and then lowercase columns that changed? Does it make a difference?

Comment: no, all that really matters is that a tail is added to differentiate the calculated columns from the originals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**base R**
This is a base R solution. It uses `sapply/ifelse` to create a matrix with the new values, then `cbind`'s it with the input dataframe `df1`.

```
cols_to_change <- c("A", "B", "C")

tmp <- sapply(cols_to_change, function(x){
  x2 <- tolower(x)
  y <- tolower(df1[["Column_name"]])
  ifelse(x2 == y, df1[["NEW"]], df1[[x]])
})
colnames(tmp) <- paste0(colnames(tmp), "_new")
df2 <- cbind(df1, tmp)

rm(tmp)    # final cleanup
```

**`dplyr` solution.**

```
newcol <- function(x, DF){
  x <- deparse(substitute(x))
  x2 <- tolower(x)
  y <- tolower(DF[["Column_name"]])
  ifelse(x2 == y, DF[["NEW"]], DF[[x]])
}

df1 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(cols_to_change), 
            .funs = funs(new=newcol(., df1)))
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- 
structure(list(Name = c("bob", "bob", "bob", "john", "john"), 
date = c(12302019L, 12102019L, 10242019L, 10062017L, 11052018L),
A = c(2, 2, 2, 684, 684), B = c(23, 23, 23, 452, 452), 
C = c(153, 153, 153, 1, 1), NEW = c(2, 362, 7, 254, 1), 
Column_name = c("a", "a", "a", "c", "c")), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Unfortunately when used with the dataset this did not work, it converted all factors to integers but in the new columns, rather than displaying what the values were in the past, they simply reflected what was in the columns with the most recent values I.e the values in column A B C,

Comment: @DominicNaimool I don't understand, which are the factors? Those columns seem to be numeric. Can you post either `str(df1)` or, better yet, `dput(df1)`  in the question?